# Make <li> not scrollable in <ul>

Tags: html, css

I have the `<ul>` like this.

[image]

I want the text "You have 3 reminders." not scrolling and stay on top.
How can I do that?

In the `<ul>` I have some code like this.

```
<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" id="reminder"
style="max-height: 200px; width: 400px; overflow: hidden; 
overflow-y: scroll; padding-left: 10px; padding-right: 10px;"></ul>
```

Thank for your help.

Comment: by the way, I use bootstrap .css in my application.

Comment: You're looking for [Affix](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#affix), but you need to setup explicitly for each of your `li` header on which position they should be fixed at

Comment: add the `position: fixed` to `<li>` header? @choz

Comment: Yes, that's affix behavior in bootstrap. But each header would have different top position. It's easier to help if you can provide a fiddle.

Comment: this jsfiddle.net/bLkyL5pv , sorry for the rude code @choz

Comment: Your fiddle messed up. And sorry to notice this now, but you don't need affix to achieve this. I created this [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nzsenrzo/) if this is what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: But if your header is already in `li`, and impossible to restructure it, you can also do it with `affix` like [This fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nzsenrzo/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try to set the "You Have 3 Reminders" As the header and the rest mainly as content?

Something like this:
HTML

```
<article>
    <header>You Have 3 Reminders</header>

    <p id="ArticleTitle">Task Satu by admin to admin</p>

    <p id="Content">You have <b>Two Days Before</b> Reminder.</p>
</article>
```

CSS

```
    ​#header {
        height:50px;
        width:100%;
        position:fixed;
        top:0;
        left:0;    
    }
.ArticleTitle{
    top:10;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can experiment with `position: fixed` to get the result.

Another option is to use `position: sticky` Although it isn't available in all browsers. [Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position) is a reference to positioning.

Comment: my `ul` become like this, when I add the `position: fixed` in my `li` header

https://postimg.org/image/a5wndt07h/

Comment: @Amirul I might be able to help you more if you can add a snippet or fiddle. Meanwhile you can try adding a `div` and making it `fixed`

Comment: btw if you're not targeting old browsers, `position: sticky` does the trick easily.

Comment: sorry but, that `position: sticky` still make my header scrollable, I use the latest chrome